# Maximum efficient word length for a given generating set

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, reference-request

The following is a generalization of a graph theory problem I have seen some work on. I would be interested to know if this question has a name, or if there has been any work outside of the graph-theoretic context.

> First, let $G$ be a finitely-generated group, with $S$ a finite generating set. There should probably be the condition that $S$ is somehow "linearly independent."
>
> Now, given a $g\in G$, we denote $r(g,S)$ to be the minimum word length over all expressions of $g$ from elements in $S$. Then define $r(G,S) = \max_{g\in G} r(g,S)$. We can think of $r(G,S)$ as a measure of how expensive it is to use $S$ in generating $G$.

Some questions might be: what does $r(G,S)$ tell us about the relationship between $S$ and $G$? What are the possible values of $r(G,S)$ over different choices of $S$? Do there exist bounds for $r(G,S)$ independent of $S$? Are there easy ways of computing $r(G,S)$?

---

The context I have seen this problem in is as follows. Let $\Gamma = (V,E)$ be a simple connected graph where $V = \{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$. Then we have the setup

$$G = S_n; \quad S = \{(i~j):(v_i,v_j)\in E\}$$

or

$$G = S_n; \quad S = \{(i_1,\dots i_k):(v_{i_1},\dots, v_{i_k})\text{ is a cycle or edge in }\Gamma\}.$$

For some examples, we have that $r(S_n, S)=3$ when $S$ is of the first type and $\Gamma = C_4$, and that $r(S_n, S)=4$ when $S$ is of the first type and $\Gamma = Q_3$, the cube graph. [This paper](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/%7Efan/ron/papers/93_07_routing.pdf) and [this paper](http://people.math.sc.edu/lu/papers/routingnumber.pdf) give more results when $S$ is of the first type. Moreover, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.04978.pdf) shows that determining whether or not $r(g,S)\le k$ for $k\ge 3$ is NP-complete.

---

Comment: Should $G$ actually be finite, or are you allowing infinite values of $r(G, S)$?

Comment: You might be interested in [Dehn functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehn_function). These measure how "loops" grow as you get further from the origin (loops correspond to the trivial element). Interestingly, such functions are, in a certain sense, invariants of the group (changing the generating set does not change the funciton asymptotically). However, Dehn functions are only really of interest for infinite groups.

Comment: Alternatively, you might be interested in ["God's algorithm" and "God's number"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_solutions_for_Rubik%27s_Cube) - given the generating set of half- and quarter-turns $S$ for the Rubix's cube group $G$, the goal (if I am interpreting everything correctly) was to find $r(G, S)$ (dubbed "God's number"). It turns out that here, $r(G, S)=20$. If $T$ is the set of quarter-face turns then $r(G, T)=26$.